# What is the difference between hitherto and heretofore?

Tags: difference

*Hitherto*:

> **Definition**:
> Until now or until a particular time:\
>
> **Example**: 
> Mira revealed *hitherto* unsuspected talents on the dance floor.

*heretofore*:

> **Definition**: 
> Until this time, before now
>
> **Examples**: 
> *Heretofore* her writing has never displayed such depth of feeling.
> This technology has created *heretofore* unimaginable possibilities.

Both terms have the sense of "sth being the case or not being the case for a long time till this point of time"

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: What is your question? Are you unsure about the difference between them? I already edited to improve your formatting, but I am not sure what's your question, so you have to edit it by yourself.

Comment: Yes I'm asking for the difference between these two words. I edited the question.

Comment: [They](https://grammarist.com/usage/heretofore-or-hitherto/) [are](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-heretofore-and-hitherto) [the](https://wikidiff.com/heretofore/hitherto) [same](https://www.justlearn.com/what-is-the-difference-between-heretofore-and-hitherto)

Comment: "Heretofore means until now, up to THIS moment in time.

Hitherto means until then, up to THAT moment in time."

What are your thoughts on this observation made by user Brian Gorton on Quora.com ("what is the difference between heretofore and Hitherto"?) I just found this article

Comment: Blokes on Quora are not authorities.

Comment: Where did you get those 'definitions'?

Comment: Did you not see the part where I mentioned Quora.com?

Comment: Some user by the name Brian Gorton posted that definition

Comment: My understanding of the two terms is now all over that place. First my view was that it meant "up until now". Now we have "up until a point in the past" and "up to a particular point in time under discussion (perhaps hinting at a future tense, from the present until the future point)"

Comment: Yes, future too, since that could be a 'time under discussion', but not necessarily or only 'from the present' until the future point'.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'vs' in the title is a way of asking 'What is the difference between these words?' the *dictionary answer* would be 'none'. They are synonyms. Both mean 'until now or until a particular time', although some dictionaries do not clarify this well.

If 'vs' means 'Which of these is better?', my *opinion* would be 'probably hitherto by a slight margin', because 'heretofore', , is generally regarded as (a) very formal (b) somewhat archaic (c) confined to legal or technical contexts.

Most style advisors would say that 'hitherto' is old-fashioned too, verging on archaic. An editor would probably ask 'Why not use *until now (or then)* , *before*, *previously*, or *so far*?'. Unless you were deliberately striving for a heavy, formal, stuffy, or archaic style, that editor would be right.

> hitherto
>
> adverb
>
> formal
>
> **until now or until a particular time**:
>
> **Synonyms**
>
> **heretofore** formal or specialized

[Hitherto (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hitherto)

Up to the present:

> We have hitherto considered how the law regards that species of
> so-called artificial persons which we know as the corporation.
>
> Here, the railway and the A9 trunk road, which have hitherto run close
> together, diverge
>
> I tell you now what we have heretofore kept secret from you.
>
> I can be of more service vis-à-vis your ambitions than I have
> heretofore.
>
> The extensive coal fields of the state have heretofore been alluded
> to.

Up to a point in the past:

> As a result, workers who had hitherto been reliable now neglected
> their work.
>
> The weather, which had hitherto been sunny and mild, suddenly turned
> cold.
>
> For each week of the study, a calculation was made for all subjects
> who had heretofore demonstrated little or no improvement as to
> the likelihood of converting to a positive response
>
> He had honorably fulfilled every promise he had heretofore made

Note that there is a word, 'hithertofore', which is widely regarded as an erroneous blending of these, although it has been found in printed works as far back as 1708. My remarks above apply even more strongly to this word.

[Heretofore or hitherto (Grammarist)](https://grammarist.com/usage/heretofore-or-hitherto/#:%7E:text=Heretofore%20is%20a%20very%20formal,are%20synonyms%20and%20severely%20unpopular.)

[A hithertofore unrecognized neologism](https://glossographia.com/2013/10/06/a-hithertofore-unrecognized-neologism/)

Comment: "Heretofore means until now, up to THIS moment in time. Hitherto means until then, up to THAT moment in time." What are your thoughts on this observation made by user Brian Gorton on Quora.com ("what is the difference between heretofore and Hitherto"?) I just found this article

Comment: @azmuth 'hitherto' means 'until now or until the point in time under discussion.' When used in the 'up to now' sense it is synonymous with 'heretofore'. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heretofore)

Comment: 'Heretofore' can also be used to mean 'up to a point in time under discussion' -  'For each week of the study, a calculation was made for all subjects who **had** heretofore demonstrated little or no improvement as to the likelihood of converting to a positive response'.